# Vim: how to move the command line to a split

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using MacVim, trying to move the bottom/command line buffer to a split.  I'd like to have my code on the left, the command line to the right.  The command line doesn't seem to behave like a regular split.  This would be useful to me because I have a REPL jacked in to Mvim and I'd like to see the output vertically, side-by-side with my code.  Any way to move the command line to a split?

Comment: No that's not possible. But a couple of minutes on Google will give you many screen/tmux-based solutions and even a few purely Vim-based ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the command-line nor the command-line window can be moved. They will always be located at the bottom, across the entire width.

If you try to issue window-movement commands like `<C-w>K`, Vim complains with `E11: Invalid in command-line window; <CR> executes, CTRL-C quits`.

Following `:help E11`, the following explanation is given:

```
The command-line window is not a normal window.  It is not possible to move to
another window or edit another buffer.  All commands that would do this are
disabled in the command-line window.  Of course it _is_ possible to execute
any command that you entered in the command-line window.  Other text edits are
discarded when closing the window.
```